# Results change based on non-modifying code

Tags: c++, string, c++11, insert

I am working off of a linux server, and I am trying to work with strings as lengths of DNA. I am trying to see if I can make one set of DNA "collide" with another set. Collide just means that two sequences are the same, but they did not originate from the same length of DNA.

Here is the data, in 5test.txt:

```
03111
11013
22002
22133
33122
33121
```

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include        <iostream>
#include        <fstream>
#include        <string>
#include        <vector>
#include        <cstdlib>
#include        <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

inline string insert(const string& who, int where, string what)
{
        string temp = who;
        temp.insert(where, what);
        return temp;
}

struct c_mDNA                               //holds the DNA sequences, remembering where it came from
{
        string seq;
        const string* orig;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, c_mDNA& m) //to print out debug info easier
{
        os << "seq: " << m.seq << "\torig: " << *m.orig << endl;
        return os;
}

int main()
{

        ifstream input; string inputname;               //These next couple lines deal with input
        inputname = "5test.txt";
        input.open(inputname.c_str());
        string line;                                    //line will hold the inputted lines
        int n = 5;                                      //we're working with length 5 as a test
        vector<string> oDNA;                            //this holds all of the original strands
        vector<c_mDNA> mDNA, iDNA;                      //this will hold all of the mutated strands, m being the deleted and i being the possible insertions

        //input loop
        while (getline(input, line))
        {
                //change line from a sequence of numbers to nucleotide ACTG
                ...
                oDNA.push_back(line);
        }

        //insert loop
        for(auto oliga : oDNA)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                        iDNA.push_back(c_mDNA { insert(oliga, i, "A"), &oliga } );
                        cout << iDNA.back() << endl;
                        //do the above for the other 3 nucleotides
                        ...                            
                }

                //these next couple lines are important

                //for (auto m : iDNA)
                //{
                //      cout  << m << endl;
                //}
        }

        //mutate loop
        for (auto& oliga : oDNA)
        {   
                for (int i = 0; i < oliga.length(); i++)
                {
                        string temp = oliga;
                        temp.erase(i,1);

                        //There are 16 different combinations of two nucleotides
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "AA", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "CA", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "TA", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "GA", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "AC", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "CC", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "TC", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "GC", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "AT", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "CT", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "TT", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "GT", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "AG", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "CG", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "TG", &oliga});
                        mDNA.push_back(c_mDNA{temp + "GG", &oliga});

                }
        }

        //check loop
        for (auto m : iDNA)
        {
                cout  << m << endl;
        }

        ofstream out("5out_test.txt");    
        int collisions(0);

        //output loop
        for (const auto& m_oliga : mDNA)
        {
                bool collide = false; c_mDNA collude;   //collude stores the collided codeword
                for (const auto& i_oliga : iDNA)
                {
                        if (m_oliga.seq == i_oliga.seq) //if sequences are the same
                        {
                                if ( m_oliga.orig != i_oliga.orig) //if the original seqs are the same
                                {
                                        cout << *m_oliga.orig << " and " << *i_oliga.orig << endl;
                                        cout << m_oliga.orig << " and " << i_oliga.orig << endl;
                                        collide = true;
                                        collude = i_oliga;
                                        collisions++;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }

                if (collide) out << m_oliga.seq << "    orig: " << *m_oliga.orig << "   collides with: " << collude.seq << " from: " << *collude.orig << endl;
                else out << m_oliga.seq << "    orig: " << *m_oliga.orig << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I have labelled the five loops "input", "insert", "mutate" "check" and "output". there is a copy of the "check" loop inside of the "insert" loop that I have commented out.

This is creeping me out. When I leave that copy commented, I get garbage like this output from the "check" loop:

```
 seq: GCGTAT     orig: GCGTAT
```

orig should be a length 5 string, and it should be pointing to an element in the  oDNA vector. From the "output" loop, when it finds a collision, it prints this out to the screen:

```
GGGTA and
0x61cf80 and 0x7fffffffd6a0
```

the first line doesn't print anything for *i_oliga.orig. The pointer is still pointing somewhere.

Now when I  uncomment the first "check" loop:

```
seq: GCGTAT     orig: GCGTT

GGGTA and GCGTT
0x61cf80 and 0x7fffffffd650
```

For some reason, the pointer is still pointing to a completely different place, but I am getting the answer that I want. i have tested to make sure that this is consistent behavior.

Why does the commented out loop change the results?

Another thing that might be useful to know is that when I import main.cpp and 5test.txt to my home computer and run the program on visual studio 15, I only ever get garbage results.

Comment: @user4581301 If you come back soon, I can put that in in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just a typo and if OP comes back and says it's a typo, I'll delete the answer.

In

```
for (auto oliga : oDNA)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        iDNA.push_back(c_mDNA { insert(oliga, i, "A"), &oliga });
    }
}
```

`auto oliga` defines a temporary variable that is a copy of the source in `oDNA`. It will go out of scope and become invalid at the close brace at the end of the loop. After passing that close brace, using that-which-was-`oliga` in any way is undefined behaviour and the compiler can generate whatever code it wants.

Assuming stack-based temporary storage, what could be happening is space is made for `oliga` on the stack and adding that extra code moves where in the stack the variable winds up. Because it's on the stack, other variables on the stack will overwrite `oliga` after it's no longer in scope, so pretty much anything could be printed from nothing to reams of utter crap until a program-crashing stack overflow occurs.

But the C++ standard would be just fine with the compiler generating code which orders a nuclear strike to wipe out all mankind. Undefined behaviour is weird.

Solution:

```
for (auto & oliga : oDNA)
```

take a reference to the original value in the `oDNA` vector to preserve the address of the value in the vector. This should be safe because it doesn't look like the `oDNA` vector is modified after this point. Typically storing pointers to values inside a `std::vector` is risky as the code is one `vector` resize away form carrying around invalid, "dangling" pointers.

Comment: Yeah, this was the solution. I had to present the code in a meeting very shortly after I posted the question and found this. There were other problems with the code, but this was the most flagrant.